# Android 4.2 adjustPan

Tags: android, android-edittext, adjustpan

I need help, I have been searching for hours a solution to this problem without success... I have an EditText inside a ViewGroup, when I click on this editText the virtual keyboard is shown. The problem is that on Android 4.2+ devices everything works as expected, the edittext is pushed up. On pre 4.2 devices the edittext stays behind the keyboard.

I have tried this on the manifest file but nothing change:

```
<activity
  ...
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> //or adjustResize
</activity>
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, use this for your editText:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: Thanks but is not working, SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE makes the keyboard appear automatically and thats not what I want, and the edittext stays behind like always (on pre 4.2 devices)